# Getting copied files

Tags: java

I want to copy the files from one folder into subfolder and then rename the filenames, i get created the subfolder and got the filenames renamed, with this part:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    String oldDir = path2;
    String oldName = list[i].toString();

    String newDir =oldDir+"\\sub";
    File pDir = new File(newDir);
    pDir.mkdir();
    String fileName = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy_HH-mm-ss")
    .format(new Date());
    String newName = fileName+"_"+list[i].getName();

    File f = new File (oldDir, list[i].getName());
    if(f.renameTo(new File(newDir + newName))){
        System.out.println("File is moved successful!");
    }else{
        System.out.println("File is failed to move!");
    }}
}
```

but i can't get copied this renamed file into new subfolder, it renamed it in parent directory instead of old filename, where did i mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is on the 'if' line:

```
if(f.renameTo(new File(newDir + newName))){
```

The problem is that you're referencing the file object that is the old file, f, then renaming it to the new directory, which doesn't work (as NKukhar noted) because it may not copy the file as you intend.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
public static void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) {
    try {
        if (!sourceFile.exists()) {
            return;
        }
        if (!destFile.exists()) {
            destFile.createNewFile();
        }
        FileChannel source = null;
        FileChannel destination = null;
        source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
        destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
        if (destination != null && source != null) {
            destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
        }
        if (source != null) {
            source.close();
        }
        if (destination != null) {
            destination.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
}
```

first param (`sourceFile`) is the file that you wanna copy, and the `destFile` is the file that you want to copy it to (which would be in your subfolder), and with your new file name

Answer (score 0):

There are some cases in documentation to [File.renameTo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29) when file cannot be moved:

```
     * Many aspects of the behavior of this method are inherently
     * platform-dependent: The rename operation might not be able to move a
     * file from one filesystem to another, it might not be atomic, and it
     * might not succeed if a file with the destination abstract pathname
     * already exists.  The return value should always be checked to make sure
     * that the rename operation was successful.
```